# Pyzo is not starting on windows 11

Tags: windows, manifest, side-by-side, pyzo, activation-context-api

I'm having trouble with my new computer.
I just get it, with windows 11 and I install Pyzo (with Anaconda) and when i'm starting Pyzo,it's written :

> "The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect Windows 10"

And when I checking the event viewer, the error is

> Creation of activation context failed for "C: \ Program Files \ pyzo \ pyzo.exe". Error in manifest or policy file "C: \ Program Files \ pyzo \ pyzo.exe" at line 15. The application element appears as a child of the urn: schemas-microsoft-com: asm.v1 element ^ dependentAssembly; this situation is not supported by this version of Windows.

Some ideas to solve it ?

Thanks

Jules